# MediaCodec - How to concatenate two mp4 files' audio streams into a single unified format and mux them back

Tags: android, audio, android-mediacodec

So I've succeeded in concatenating the video streams of more than 1 video files using MediaCodec - with as many `MediaExtractor`s and decoder `MediaCodec`s as the video files. Now my question is about concatenating said videos' audio streams.

Using the modified ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMux test, I tried the same method I used to concatenate the video streams for the audio streams, making sure that the final audio encoder has a single preset format:

```
private void audioExtractorLoop(MediaExtractor localAudioExtractor, MediaCodec destinationAudioDecoder, ByteBuffer[] dstAudioDecoderInputBuffers)
{
    //Audio Extractor code begin
    boolean localAudioExtractorIsOriginal = (localAudioExtractor == audioExtractor);
    boolean localDone = localAudioExtractorIsOriginal ? audioExtractorDone : audioExtractorAppendDone;
    Log.i("local_audio_extractor", localAudioExtractorIsOriginal+" "+localDone);

    while (mCopyAudio && !localDone && (encoderOutputAudioFormat == null || muxing)) {
        int decoderInputBufferIndex = destinationAudioDecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
        if (decoderInputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "no audio decoder input buffer");
            break;
        }
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "audio decoder: returned input buffer: "
                    + decoderInputBufferIndex);
        }
        ByteBuffer decoderInputBuffer = dstAudioDecoderInputBuffers[decoderInputBufferIndex];
        int size = localAudioExtractor.readSampleData(decoderInputBuffer, 0);
        long presentationTime = localAudioExtractor.getSampleTime();
        if(localAudioExtractorIsOriginal)currentFrameTimestamp = presentationTime;
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "audio extractor: returned buffer of size "
                    + size);
            Log.d(TAG, "audio extractor: returned buffer for time "
                    + presentationTime);
        }
        if (size >= 0) {
            destinationAudioDecoder.queueInputBuffer(decoderInputBufferIndex, 0,
                    size, presentationTime,
                    localAudioExtractor.getSampleFlags());
        }
        localDone = !localAudioExtractor.advance();
        if (localDone) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "audio extractor: EOS");
            if(localAudioExtractorIsOriginal) {
                initAudioExtractorFinalTimestamp = currentFrameTimestamp;
                audioExtractorDone = true;
            }
            destinationAudioDecoder.queueInputBuffer(decoderInputBufferIndex, 0,
                    0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
        }
        audioExtractedFrameCount++;
        break;
    }
    //Audio Extractor code end
}

private void localizedAudioDecoderLoop(MediaCodec localAudioDecoder)
{
    boolean localAudioDecoderIsOriginal = (localAudioDecoder == audioDecoder);
    boolean localDone = localAudioDecoderIsOriginal ? audioDecoderDone : audioDecoderAppendDone;

    Log.i("local_audio_decoder", localAudioDecoderIsOriginal+"");
    ByteBuffer[] localDecoderOutByteBufArray = localAudioDecoderIsOriginal ? audioDecoderOutputBuffers : audioDecoderAppendOutputBuffers;
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo localDecoderBufInfo = localAudioDecoderIsOriginal ? audioDecoderOutputBufferInfo : audioDecoderAppendOutputBufferInfo;
    while (mCopyAudio && !localDone && pendingAudioDecoderOutputBufferIndex == -1 && (encoderOutputAudioFormat == null || muxing)) {
        int decoderOutputBufferIndex = localAudioDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(localDecoderBufInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
        if(!localAudioDecoderIsOriginal)localDecoderBufInfo.presentationTimeUs += initAudioExtractorFinalTimestamp+33333;
        //Log.i("decoder_out_buf_info", audioDecoderOutputBufferInfo.size + " " + audioDecoderOutputBufferInfo.offset);
        if (decoderOutputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "no audio decoder output buffer");
            break;
        }
        if (decoderOutputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "audio decoder: output buffers changed");
            //audioDecoderOutputBuffers = audioDecoder.getOutputBuffers();
            localDecoderOutByteBufArray = audioDecoder.getOutputBuffers();
            break;
        }
        if (decoderOutputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            decoderOutputAudioFormat = localAudioDecoder.getOutputFormat();
            decoderOutputChannelNum = decoderOutputAudioFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT);
            decoderOutputAudioSampleRate = decoderOutputAudioFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);
            if (VERBOSE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "audio decoder: output format changed: "
                        + decoderOutputAudioFormat);
            }
            break;
        }
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "audio decoder: returned output buffer: "
                    + decoderOutputBufferIndex);
        }
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "audio decoder: returned buffer of size "
                    + localDecoderBufInfo.size);
        }
        ByteBuffer decoderOutputBuffer = localDecoderOutByteBufArray[decoderOutputBufferIndex];
        if ((localDecoderBufInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "audio decoder: codec config buffer");
            localAudioDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderOutputBufferIndex,
                    false);
            break;
        }
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "audio decoder: returned buffer for time "
                    + localDecoderBufInfo.presentationTimeUs);
        }
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "audio decoder: output buffer is now pending: "
                    + pendingAudioDecoderOutputBufferIndex);
        }
        pendingAudioDecoderOutputBufferIndex = decoderOutputBufferIndex;
        audioDecodedFrameCount++;
        break;
    }

    while (mCopyAudio && pendingAudioDecoderOutputBufferIndex != -1) {
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "audio decoder: attempting to process pending buffer: "
                            + pendingAudioDecoderOutputBufferIndex);
        }
        int encoderInputBufferIndex = audioEncoder
                .dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
        if (encoderInputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "no audio encoder input buffer");
            break;
        }
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "audio encoder: returned input buffer: "
                    + encoderInputBufferIndex);
        }
        ByteBuffer encoderInputBuffer = audioEncoderInputBuffers[encoderInputBufferIndex];
        int size = localDecoderBufInfo.size;
        long presentationTime = localDecoderBufInfo.presentationTimeUs;
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "audio decoder: processing pending buffer: "
                    + pendingAudioDecoderOutputBufferIndex);
        }
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "audio decoder: pending buffer of size " + size);
            Log.d(TAG, "audio decoder: pending buffer for time "
                    + presentationTime);
        }
        if (size >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer decoderOutputBuffer = localDecoderOutByteBufArray[pendingAudioDecoderOutputBufferIndex]
                    .duplicate();

            byte[] testBufferContents = new byte[size];
            //int bufferSize = (extractorInputChannelNum == 1 && decoderOutputChannelNum == 2) ? size / 2 : size;
            float samplingFactor = (decoderOutputChannelNum/extractorInputChannelNum) * (decoderOutputAudioSampleRate / extractorAudioSampleRate);
            int bufferSize = size / (int)samplingFactor;
            Log.i("sampling_factor", samplingFactor+" "+bufferSize);

            if (decoderOutputBuffer.remaining() < size) {
                for (int i = decoderOutputBuffer.remaining(); i < size; i++) {
                    testBufferContents[i] = 0;  // pad with extra 0s to make a full frame.
                }
                decoderOutputBuffer.get(testBufferContents, 0, decoderOutputBuffer.remaining());
            } else {
                decoderOutputBuffer.get(testBufferContents, 0, size);
            }

            //WARNING: This works for 11025-22050-44100 or 8000-16000-24000-48000
            //What about in-between?
            //BTW, the size of the bytebuffer may be less than 4096 depending on the sampling factor
            //(Now that I think about it I should've realized this back when I decoded the video result from the encoding - 2048 bytes decoded)
            if (((int)samplingFactor) > 1) {
                Log.i("s2m_conversion", "Stereo to Mono and/or downsampling");
                byte[] finalByteBufferContent = new byte[size / 2];

                for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i+=2) {
                    if((i+1)*((int)samplingFactor) > testBufferContents.length)
                    {
                        finalByteBufferContent[i] = 0;
                        finalByteBufferContent[i+1] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        finalByteBufferContent[i] = testBufferContents[i*((int)samplingFactor)];
                        finalByteBufferContent[i+1] = testBufferContents[i*((int)samplingFactor) + 1];
                    }
                }

                decoderOutputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(finalByteBufferContent);
            }

            decoderOutputBuffer.position(localDecoderBufInfo.offset);
            decoderOutputBuffer.limit(localDecoderBufInfo.offset + bufferSize);
            //decoderOutputBuffer.limit(audioDecoderOutputBufferInfo.offset + size);
            encoderInputBuffer.position(0);

            Log.d(TAG, "hans, audioDecoderOutputBufferInfo:" + localDecoderBufInfo.offset);
            Log.d(TAG, "hans, decoderOutputBuffer:" + decoderOutputBuffer.remaining());
            Log.d(TAG, "hans, encoderinputbuffer:" + encoderInputBuffer.remaining());
            encoderInputBuffer.put(decoderOutputBuffer);

            audioEncoder.queueInputBuffer(encoderInputBufferIndex, 0, bufferSize, presentationTime, localDecoderBufInfo.flags);
            //audioEncoder.queueInputBuffer(encoderInputBufferIndex, 0, size, presentationTime, audioDecoderOutputBufferInfo.flags);
        }
        audioDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(
                pendingAudioDecoderOutputBufferIndex, false);
        pendingAudioDecoderOutputBufferIndex = -1;
        if ((localDecoderBufInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "audio decoder: EOS");
            if(localDecoderBufInfo == audioDecoderOutputBufferInfo){audioDecoderDone = true;}
            else{audioDecoderAppendDone = true;}
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Into these functions I'll pass the `MediaExtractor` and decoder `MediaCodec` objects for the first audio stream and loop through them until they reach EOS, then I'll swap the `MediaExtractor` and decoder `MediaCodec` with the ones for the second audio stream.

This code works fine for the first audio stream, but after the swap I get the following stacktrace:

```
10-11 15:14:59.941 3067-22024/? E/SEC_AAC_DEC: saacd_decode() failed ret_val: -3, Indata 0x 11 90 00 00, length : 683
10-11 15:14:59.941 3067-22024/? E/SEC_AAC_DEC: ASI 0x 11, 90 00 00
10-11 15:14:59.951 29907-22020/com.picmix.mobile E/ACodec: OMXCodec::onEvent, OMX_ErrorStreamCorrupt
10-11 15:14:59.951 29907-22020/com.picmix.mobile W/AHierarchicalStateMachine: Warning message AMessage(what = 'omxI') = {
                                                                            int32_t type = 0
                                                                            int32_t event = 1
                                                                            int32_t data1 = -2147479541
                                                                            int32_t data2 = 0
                                                                          } unhandled in root state.
```

I thought the decoders would just end up decoding all audio streams to `audio/raw` type with 44100 Hz sample rate and 2 channels, so the encoder can just take the data and encode to a final format.

What extra considerations will I have to take for audio, and how can I prevent the audio stream being corrupt when I swap Extractor-Decoder pairs?

EDIT:

I added these lines to check the contents of the extracted samples in `MediaExtractor`:

```
ByteBuffer decoderInputBuffer = dstAudioDecoderInputBuffers[decoderInputBufferIndex];
        int size = localAudioExtractor.readSampleData(decoderInputBuffer, 0);
        long presentationTime = localAudioExtractor.getSampleTime();
        //new lines begin
        byte[] debugBytes = new byte[decoderInputBuffer.remaining()];
        decoderInputBuffer.duplicate().get(debugBytes);
        Log.i(TAG, "DEBUG - extracted frame: "+ audioExtractedFrameCount +" | bytebuffer contents: "+new String(debugBytes));
        //new lines end
```

In the `decoderInputBuffer.duplicate().get(debugBytes);` line, I get the `IllegalStateException: buffer is inaccessible` error.

Does this mean I set up the extractor wrong?

EDIT 2:

When I looked into it further, it's only a problem with the appending audio extractor, not the first audio extractor.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something completely stupid. Earlier in the code when I was setting up the decoder buffers, I did this:

```
audioDecoderInputBuffers = audioDecoder.getInputBuffers();
audioDecoderOutputBuffers = audioDecoder.getOutputBuffers();
audioDecoderAppendInputBuffers = audioDecoder.getInputBuffers();
audioDecoderAppendOutputBuffers = audioDecoder.getOutputBuffers();
```

They were referring to the same decoder instance.